# Helm3 - validation: chart.metadata is required

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm in the learning phase of Helm. I'm trying to create helm chart with simple pod definition file. But it's failed with the below error.

Note : If i'm trying to run this command `helm install --values=ghost-values.yaml stable/ghost --generate-name`. It works fine. Basically this download and install the chart from remote(If i'm not wrong). 
But I don't know why my local helm chart that I created not working.

```
➜  Helm $ helm version --short
v3.2.0+ge11b7ce
➜  Helm $
```

Folder path ->

```
➜  Helm $ ls guestbook
Chart.yml templates
➜  Helm $
```

Chart.yml file

```
➜  guestbook $ cat Chart.yml
apiVersion: v2
name: guestbook
appVersion: "1.0"
description: A Helm chart for Guestbook 1.0
version: 0.1.0
type: application
➜  guestbook $
```

template file

```
➜  guestbook $ cat templates/web.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: pod
  name: pod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: pod
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - webserver
        image: nginx
        name: pod
        resources: {}
status: {}
➜  guestbook $
```

Error:

```
➜  Helm $ helm install demo-guestbook guestbook
Error: validation: chart.metadata is required
➜  Helm $
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename `Chart.yml` to `Chart.yaml`, then run again. [Here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f/pkg/chart/loader/load.go#L79) it expects the name should be `Chart.yaml`

Comment: My Chart filename was already called `Chart.yaml` so I created a symlink from `chart.yaml` to `Chart.yaml` and re-ran the `helm install` command and it worked .  This (to me) makes no sense based on looking at the link/script which uses `Chart.yaml`